# How to get values from subcollection in firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection named 'course' and it has some documents all of them have a subCollection
named 'sem' and it also has some documents. I attached screenshot below. I need to get all values in subCollection 'sem' can anyone please help

[image]
[image]

Comment: `FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("course").document("your-document-id").collection("sem")`

Answer (score 2):

Hello when you save a new course , you will need to save in the new document an id that reflect that courses document id  for when you need to delete it or update it like that :
exemple for firestore

```
final firestoreInstance = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
      await firestoreInstance.collection("course").add({
        'id': '123',
        'enddate': value,
        'semname': value,
        'startdate': value,
      }).then((value) async {
        firestoreInstance
            .collection("profiles")
            .doc(value.id)
            .update({
          "id": value.id,
        });
```

and for the document in sem same thing, when you add it do as above
hope I answered you question

[image: id in document like in picture]

Comment: i dont think your answer is what i need. I need semname,startdate,enddate from all documents in 'sem' subcollection

Comment: for sure but in every one to update it you will need the id document in courses to access easily the document with the sem you want to get , what you do is get all the courses and for every one show the detail on it , but to access a specific sem you will need , the entire path with every id document or for a specific sem only id of the course document and the the id of the sem document

Comment: you are telling me to add couseId in all documents in sem subcollection right. if it is i will add course id but i need to query for getting values sem documents. can you write query for that

Comment: no you add in the document itself the id document like the request show, for accuracy and to win time, and to get a specific sem document and that for every course document and when you add a new subclass document in sem the same, will become easy for use later